# Epsilon-Delta Continuity in Hyperreals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, nonstandard-analysis

I am wondering what's exactly the reason why we do not use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity in Hyperreals? I mean, I know that one of the purposes of building this set is that we replace that $\epsilon-\delta$  concept with infinitesimals. But there must be some other reasons, right? Will that $\epsilon-\delta$ definition still work in Hyperreals? Cheers!

Comment: In Robinson's book *Non-Standard Analysis* he discusses the notion called "$S$-continuous".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the epsilon-delta definition does work in the hyperreals.  This is because the epsilon-delta definition is a first-order formula, meaning that quantification is only over elements (not over sets, as in the completeness property of the real field).  Thus, a real function $f$ is continuous at a real point $c$ if $$(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x) \big[|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon\big].$$  By the transfer principle applied to this first-order formula, it is still valid over the hyperreals: $$(\forall \epsilon\in{}^\ast\mathbb R^+)(\exists\delta\in{}^\ast\mathbb R^+)(\forall x\in{}^\ast\mathbb R) \big[|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon\big].$$  This is now true for all positive values of $\epsilon$, for instance if $\epsilon$ is a positive infinitesimal.  In the second formula $f$ denotes the natural extension of the real function $f$ (sometimes this is denoted ${}^\ast\! f$ but the asterisk is usually deleted when dealing with functions when the meaning is unambiguous).

As to your question "But there must be some other reasons, right?" you may be interested in our work where we developed a framework for [differential geometry via infinitesimal displacements](http://www.logicandanalysis.com/index.php/jla/article/view/237):

> Nowik, Tahl; Katz, Mikhail G. Differential geometry via infinitesimal displacements. J. Log. Anal. 7 (2015), Paper 5, 44 pp.

There is actually a subtle difference between the two definitions of continuity: (A) "continuity" at $x$ via epsilon-delta, and (B) "microcontinuity" at $x$ via Cauchy's idea of requiring that for each infinitesimal $\Delta x=\alpha$, the change in function $\Delta y=f(x+\alpha)-f(x)$ is also infinitesimal.

The two definitions (A) and (B) are equivalent when applied at a real point $x=c$, namely $c\in\mathbb R$.  However, in general they may not be equivalent.  For example, if $f(x)=x^2$ and $x=H$ is infinite, then $f$ will be continuous at $x=H$ but *not* microcontinuous at $x=H$.

In fact, uniform continuity of a real function $f$ on, say, $\mathbb R$ is equivalent to microcontinuity of ${}^\ast\! f$ at all points of ${}^\ast\mathbb R$.  Meanwhile, continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb R$ is equivalent to microcontinuity at all *real* points $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: But then why don't we use that definition? And anyway, will that definition still work if the function is defined over infinitesimals, i.e. $f:\Delta\rightarrow\Delta$ where $\Delta$ is set of infinitesimals? Thanks heaps!

Comment: This definition is correct and therefore we can certainly use it :-) In my experience in teaching freshman calculus, students find the definition using infinitesimals (without alternating quantifiers) more comprehensible.  That definition says that whenever $\alpha$ is infinitesimal, the change in the function $f(x+\alpha)-f(x)$ is also infinitesimal.  You've gotta admit that's simpler :-)

Comment: A function defined only on infinitesimals will not be of much use in the calculus.  Generally one deals with functions that are natural extensions of real functions (as in the *answer*).

Comment: Yep I agree that the infinitesimals definition is much easier to understand and yep, a function defined only on infinitesimals will not be of much use. However, they do exist right? So yea, my question remains: will that $\epsilon-\delta$ definition work on that function? ;-)

Comment: @AngghaNugraha The definitions are provably equivalent, in the sense that you can assume one and prove the other also holds as a consequence.

Comment: @AngghaNugraha, if the domain $D$ of a real function $f$ includes an open interval $(-r,r)$ for some real $r>0$ then in particular the natural extension ${}^\ast D$ will include all the infinitesimals.  Then the definition of continuity of $f$ at any point $c\in D$ (including $0$) will also be satisfied by restriction for all infinitesimal $x$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: OK cool! I am reading your paper now. Thanks heaps!

Comment: @AlecRhea: Yep I know that they're equivalent. I'm just wondering why Robinson prefers that infinitesimals concept to the $\epsilon-\delta$ one. :-)

Comment: @AngghaNugraha,: (1) there is actually a subtle point here which makes that they are not completely equivalent.  I will try to elaborate in my answer.  (2) Robinson in his book gives many applications of his framework for analysis with infinitesimals, including in applied mathematics; see e.g., [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/157298/28128).

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Oh nice! I am looking forward to your elaboration then! ;-) Also thanks for the reference to that post about Robinson. Cheers!

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Hmm I don't really understand the first sentence on your last paragraph there. Is it because we have $\delta$ for the whole set $\mathbb{R}$ where that function $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Well the proof is somewhat nontrivial.  I can provide sources if you are interested.  I am assuming you are referring to the fact that uniform continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb R$ is equivalent to microcontinuity at all points of ${}^\ast\mathbb R$.